# GTK+3 config Arch/LXDE

Tags: arch-linux, gtk, lxde

I use Arch + LXDE. I performed a full system upgrade and upgraded packages seems to have included GTK+3. Since the upgrade, my GTK+3 progs such as GEdit, Evince, etc.  look somehow terrible (unusual padding between button texts and button boundaries, ...) and I don't have the `gtkrc` in home.

`pacman -S gtk3` too, can't return the RC file. What should I do? Thanks for helps.

Comment: GTK3 settings are saved in ${XDG_CONFIG_HOME}/gtk-3.0/settings.ini

Comment: I don't have the gtk-3.0 directory there.

Answer (score 2):

Because your current theme doesn't support GTK3, i.e a gtk-3.0 folder in the themes directory, all GTK3-based apps will look ugly (they will use the default built-in theme),

So simply go to [gnome-look.org](http://gnome-look.org) and find some awesome theme (in the gtk-3.0 category, which will support both GTK2 and GTK3), and put it in `~/.themes`.

To change the theme, use `lxappearance`.

Answer (score 1):

Try using a theme which provides a uniform look for GTK+ 3.x and GTK+ 2.x applications, like Zukitwo (you can find it in the AUR too https://aur.archlinux.org/packages.php?ID=49377).

Install the theme and set it with LXAppearance, which you should have already installed since you use LXDE. Otherwise

```
pacman -S lxappearance
```

It handles the configuration for both GTK versions.

Comment: Ok, but if I wanna keep this minimal theme, but just correct it's config what should I do? I mean even this crappy(ied) theme ought to have a config file somewhere, doesn't it?

Answer (score 0):

GTK+ themes installed system-wide should be in /usr/share/themes. You can copy your favourite theme directory and put it in ~/.themes. Then you start editing it. I never edited a GTK+ theme myself, so I can't help you on this.